# Angular ng-click not working in div

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

Ok, I've been stuck here for a while, and I'm sure it's something relatively dumb

http://plnkr.co/edit/YcBnbE5VCU5rizkDWreS?p=preview

```
<head>
    <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script >
        function myCtrl($scope,  $window) {
            $scope.vm = {};
            $scope.vm.Courses = [
              { Id: 1, Name: "Course 1"},
              { Id: 2, Name: "Course 2"}
              ];
            $scope.OpenCourse = function(courseId) {
                $window.alert("Called " + courseId);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div>  
        <div ng-repeat="course in vm.Courses" ng-click="vm.OpenCourse(course.Id)">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <label>{{course.Name}}</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Why isn't ng-click firing here? It seems that this question is asked a lot, but none of the answers seem to help. It also looks like moving the div out of the repeat makes it work, but again, I'm not sure why.

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Remove `vm.`

Result:

```
<div ng-repeat="course in vm.Courses" ng-click="OpenCourse(course.Id)">
```

Why?, because everything you set to `$scope` becomes available on the partial, then you just have to call it.

Answer (score 8):

The lack of "vm" in front of OpenCourse(course.Id) was actually a typo on my part when creating the plunker. I've marked an answer as correct, since it did cause the plunker to work, but my problem wasn't this. It turned out that I had a class assigned to outer div that was changing the z-index, putting that div "behind" the others, and not allowing the click to propagate.

Comment: I had a similar problem where the button was inside a <label> and ng-click was not firing. I had to restructure the layout to take the button outside and it started working then. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Please uncheck the other answer if it does not actually answer you question.

Comment: It did answer the question. The problem was that my question didn't properly express my problem

Comment: I had a similar issue and changing the z-index sorted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you use `<label>` you might experience weird behaviour when clicking on it. Try changing it to something else if possible and re-test your code.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to :

```
ng-click="OpenCourse(course.Id)"
```

[Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/okz9sNVpzOvte1y0743l?p=preview)