# ng-click not fire when on small width device

Tags: angularjs, responsive-design, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-click

I have an Angular web app  which have to be responsive. To do that i use Bootstrap and its responsive grid system.

In every page I have to interact with users to set app, or simply change page. For that, I use ng-click and ng-href directives.

I have tested it many times, it works great except when my device screen width is close to phone portrait's width. I noticed this issue when i use chrome dev tools phone emulator and check on my phone a Wiko.

Have you any clue about this problem ? it's kinda weird, isn't it  ?

**EDIT :** I added ngTouch to my app, but no change.

Comment: Any reason you're not using [ngTouch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch)?

Comment: @salniro I already added it, but not working ...

Comment: I use AngularJS and Bootstrap for mobile apps all of the time without issue.  Can you provide a Plunker?  Maybe something else is going on with your CSS where an element is overlapping the click target? Or, maybe it's some specific combination of versions.  Can't debug though without a way to reproduce it.

Comment: If you got an answer please share I'm facing the same issue. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that my ngclick item was behind div with no ng-click directive when on small screen device.
Just fixed it by revising my responsive.

Comment: Thx for answering. However, I found the answer from [Carlos Rodriguez](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27512016/angular-ng-click-not-working-in-div). Changing the z-index of the parent div solutioned my problem, I haven't figured out why yet